# Can you make AoOs against targets you can't see?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack, invisibility

In 5e, you can only make opportunity attacks against targets you can see.

I can't find similar language in 3.5, but the rules are a bit scattered.
Can an invisible attacker run circles around you without any problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't attack a target with total concealment**

The rules for Total concealment (PH p152) state (emphasis mine):

> If you have line of effect to a target but not line of sight (for
>   instance, if he is in total darkness or *invisible* or if you're
>   blinded) he is considered to have total concealment from you...
>
> You can't execute an attack of opportunity against an opponent with
>   total concealment even if you know what square or squares the opponent
>   occupies.

So an invisible opponent cannot be subjected to attacks of opportunity unless you have a way to see through the invisibility.

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't be surprised if a feat or class-feature allowed it as a special-case ;)